# Alphabetically filtering a view

Tags: views

I have a view that I need to filter alphabetically. How is this done? I need to also add a list item for each letter of the alphabet, with an ID of that letter for a quick anchor scroll-to script. Can anyone help me getting this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This video](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/742) is from Nodeone.se addresses sorting, but the entire series on Views is an excellent tutorial.

Comment: Great that was helpful. Looks like I had it done already just didn't realize it as I don't have many posts created. What I really need help with is creating a list item for each letter of the alphabet with a custom id and class. I don't need it to be a link though just an id for an anchor jump.

Comment: This isn't quite what you are describing, but check out the built in view called "Glossary" and the attachment that generates the alphabetical filtering menu at the top of the view display.

Comment: Hmm. seems close to what I need. Not sure how it works though even after looking it over.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Lexicon](https://drupal.org/project/lexicon) module will help you.

> A lexicon is a stock of terms used in a particular profession, subject or style; a vocabulary. The Lexicon module generates one or more Lexicon pages based on terms in taxonomies and optionally marks terms in the content and links them to the appropriate Lexicon page.